# Bilinear maps and non-degeneracy

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $\mathbb{G}_0$ and $\mathbb{G}_1$ be two multiplicative cyclic groups
of prime order $p$, $g$ a generator of $\mathbb{G}_0$ and $e$ a bilinear map, $e:\mathbb{G}_0\times\mathbb{G}_0\rightarrow\mathbb{G}_1$. The **bilinear map** $e$ has the following properties:

1. **Bilinearity**: for all $u,v\in\mathbb{G}_0$ e
   $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_p$, we have $e(u^a,v^b)=e(u,v)^{ab}$
2. **Non-degeneracy**: $e(g,g) \neq 1$

I don't understand the second property (non-degenerancy). Why $e(g,g)\neq 1$ ? (I don't understand $\neq 1$).

Comment: Is this because $G_1$ is a multiplicative group and hence $1$ denotes the identity element ?

Comment: I have read this @ page 4: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~bwaters/publications/papers/cp-abe.pdf

Comment: The condition $e(g,g) \neq 1$ isn't required for general bilinear maps, but is linked to the definition of [degenerate bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_bilinear_form). Indeed, if $x = g^n \in G_0$ with $0<n<p$, then $e(x,x)=e(g,g)^{n^2} \neq 1$ (since $e(g,g)$ has order $p$ in $G_1$ and $p \not \mid n^2$).

Comment: Is this the explaination of $e(g,g)\neq1$ ? I'm reading this example (http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/27360/16899) but again I don't understand what is the problem if $e(g,g)=1$ ?

Comment: In [this](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.897/spring04/L25.pdf) document, in §4.1, the "3-party Key Agreement Scheme" is explained. If $e(g,g) = 1$, then the key $K$ is just $1$, which might not be a "good" key. Moreover, on top of p. 2, one can read : « If everything maps to the identity, that’s obviously not interesting »

Comment: Perfect ! Great ! Thanks @Watson

Comment: However, the Weil pairing is alternating (i.e. $e_m(P,P)=1$), see Silverman p. 94. The Weil pairing is not used directly for cryptography: if you directly restrict the pairing to a cyclic subgroup of order m, the pairing will be trivial (as it is alternating). One way to remedy this is to use what we call a distortion map to get a distorted pairing which will not be trivial on the group and will be cryptographically interesting.